# Why react-validation hasErrors issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-validation to validate a login form. After submitting the form I want to know has an error or not. I can get the error state inside my custom button object in below way.

```
const customSubmit = ({ hasErrors, ...props }) => {
  return <Button disabled={hasErrors} >Login</Button>
  {hasErrors.toString()}/>
};
const SubmitButton = button(customSubmit);
```

Is there any way to get hasError state when submit a from?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am looking for the same thing...

Comment: No, I did not find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can share a similar code when I use State and handleChange to get the errors in the button.
First you need  a function were you declare the useState.

```
import React from "react";
import { Box, Button, Collapse, Grid, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

     function FormVal() {
      const [phone, setPhone] = React.useState<string>();
      const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState<{ phone: string }>();
      const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const {
          target: { value },
        } = event;
        setErrors({ phone: "" });
        setPhone(value);
        let reg = new RegExp(/^\d*$/).test(value);

     if (!reg) {
          setErrors({ phone: "Only numbers" });
        }
};
```

Now in the return section you need to declare the handleChange. There may be some elements that you don't know such as  and that is because I am using Material-ui.

```
     return (
    <Box className={classes.root} width="100%" padding="5px">
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={phone}
            label="phone number"
            inputProps={{ maxLength: 255 }}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            error={Boolean(errors?.phone)}
            helperText={errors?.phone}
            variant="outlined"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Collapse in={phone?.length! > 0}>
          <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <Button variant="contained">Save</Button>
          </div>
        </Collapse>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
export default FormVal;
```